# Como capturar o status (e readyState) do XHR do IE6?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Como?

```
alert(new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP").readyState);
```

<s>`// undefined`</s>

```
// 0
```

---

```
alert((new XMLHttpRequest).readyState);
// 0
```

**Edit**: no meu código, antes eu tinha modificado o `this` para `xhr` no escopo de `onreadystatechange`, mas não tinha funcionado, e depois modifiquei novamente e funcionou, quando @bfavaretto e @GuilhermeNascimento sugeriram. Acho que eu havia esquecido algo. Isso foi realmente um typo enquanto eu modificava o código, mas `this` deveria funcionar (porém não em alguns navegadores velhos como IE6).

Comment: ie6 ? cara, que sofrência...

Comment: Pode ser essa verificação de  `me.done`, não vejo essa função ser definida no seu código.

Comment: @bfavaretto Na verdade o `if` declarado antes desses 2 nem executa, o `this.readyState` é `undefined` :( . Ele está declarado, mas eu coloquei um `/* ... */`.

Comment: Vai que esse `this` no IE é outra coisa... Não custa tentar xhr.readyState...

Comment: @bfavaretto Também não... eu coloquei `xhr` e não aconteceu nada :/. O `this` é o mesmo que `xhr` no escopo de `onreadystatechange`.

Comment: Nicematt eu sei, *deveria ser*, mas no IE6, nunca se sabe ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não tenho certeza, mas suponho que o problema seja que devido ao "Ajax" no Internet Explorer 6, 7 e 8 (estes dois últimos se usados em [quirks-mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/xmlhttp.html)) usarem ActiveX e não o `XMLHttpRequest` propriamente dito deve-se fazer a checagem do ActiveX "correto", no caso tem o `Microsoft.XMLHTTP` e o `Msxml2.XMLHTTP`.

> Um detalhe muito importante é que você deve sempre usar XHR em páginas `http://`, ou seja se usar em `file:///` pode falhar.

Então se pretende dar algum suporte para IE6 e 7/8 use assim:

```
function XHR() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        return new window.XMLHttpRequest;
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
            return new window.ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e1) {
            return false;
        }

        try {
            return new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e1) {
            return false;
        }
     }
 }
```

Um detalhe que nos navegadores modernos não afeta, mas em alguns antigos ocorria eram o problema com a ordem da chamada dos métodos, por isto eu sempre usava a seguinte orderm, `.open`, `.onreadystatechange` (ou diretamente o `.readyState`) e `.send`.

O uso do código seria algo como (leia sobre o [`.readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)):

```
var foo = XHR();

foo.open("GET", "/url", true); //Usa chama assíncrona

//Use o readyState após o .open, como já dito
foo.onreadystatechange = function() {

    switch (foo.readyState) {
        case 0:
            //(não inicializado)
        break;
        case 1:
            //(carregando)
        break;
        case 2:
            //(já carregado)
        break;
        case 3:
            //(interativo)
        break;
        case 4:
            //(completo) ... Neste ponto já se pode chamar o responseText

            alert(foo.responseText);
        break;
    }
};

//Faz a requisição
foo.send(null);
```

Um exemplo com outros Activex (todavia desenvolvi muito para IEs e o código anterior funcionava desde do IE5.01+):

```
function XHR() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        return new window.XMLHttpRequest;
    }

    var XMLHttpFactories = [
        "Msxml3.XMLHTTP", "Msxml2.XMLHTTP", "Microsoft.XMLHTTP"
    ];

    var obj = false, i = 0, j = XMLHttpFactories.length;

    for (; i < j; i++) {

        try {
            obj = new window.ActiveXObject(XMLHttpFactories[i]);
        } catch (e) {
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    return obj;
}
```

> **Nota:** O `window.` é dispensável, só o usei para evitar conflitos com variáveis em outros escopos, o que pode ser quase impossível, mas é apenas para evitar.

**Uma dica,** prefira evitar (nunca usar) o sync mode:

```
foo.open("GET", "/url", false);
```

Comment: Obrigado pelos exemplos! Parece que ainda fazem o código funcionar melhor, portanto as propriedades que uso no XHR normal ainda não existem... eu acho que o nome dessas propriedades é mesmo diferente! Por causa disso não consigo fazer callbacks no IE6. Obs: `xhr.responseText` também não existe (mesmo usando `msxml[3/2]`).

Comment: @nicematt a quais propriedades se refere? O uso é quase igual até onde tenho notado, as unicas coisas que noto que são diferentes é o ActiveX para cada versão de navegador e ordem/momento que se deve chamar o  `.readyState` (principalmente em navegadores antigos).

Comment: @nicematt uso `xhr.responseText` e `xhr.responseText` normalmente no IE5.01 e IE6 (ainda tenho ele instalado para testes), deve ser alguma coisa em que você esta se confundindo.

Comment: Sim, as propriedades `readyState`, `status` e `responseText` estão indefinidas ! Eu acho que o problema é o programa que estou usando no Windows para testar o IE. Talvez ele seja incompleto, certo? Pode me dizer o nome do seu?

Comment: Obs: eu faço a requisição AJAX do jeito como faz seu código.

Comment: @nicematt Tenho instalado o IE5.01 e 6 "reais" em uma máquina virtual, todavia testei no IETester e funcionou normalmente também. Testou o exemplo que lhe enviei, note que editei a resposta, adicione detalhes sobre a ordem do open/readyState/send e sobre o momento de usar responseText ... Me envie o nome do programa que esta usando.

Comment: O seu código puro funcionou. Acho que eu devo ter um erro de digito no meu. Quando eu deixei sobrar só aquele `"Microsoft.XMLHTTP"` na array  `XMLHttpFactories` também funcionou. Eu havia postado o meu código na pergunta antes, mas parece que não tinha problema... :o Isso parece uma magia! Vou tentar me adaptar nesse código agora.

Comment: @nicematt certa vez usando `event.keyCode`, e sempre retornava undefined, mas após um dia me dei conta que eu tinha escrito o C e minusculo: `.keycode`... PS: Se quiser mandar o código original na pergunta, só para eu ver, ou usando o http://pastebin.com me avisa ae eu vejo ele.

Comment: Beleza... vou tentar achar o novo erro depois de eu ter editado ele, e assim vou enviar no pastebin.

Comment: @nicematt eu achei, e testei, o problema é que foram duas situações, a primeira era o uso do `this` que não funciona para os IEs e o segundo quando usou `new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP").readyState` era devido a ordem da chamada dos métodos, que nos IEs é necessário usar open/onreadystatechange/send.

Comment: Sim, eu estava fazendo nessa ordem, e eu tinha testado usar `xhr` em vez de `this` no escopo do `onreadystatechange`, mas também não tinha funcionado... talvez isso seja relacionado ao escopo das minhas funções em `exports`.

Comment: @nicematt sim, entendo, mas me referi ao momento que usou `alert(new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP").readyState);`, todavia acho que já esta funcional para os IEs :)

Comment: O estranho é que resultou em `0` quando eu executei esse `alert`... eu pensei que seria `undefined` se eu usasse meu outro código, mas eu fiz um teste e deu `0` mesmo. Há um problema de escopo lá para navegadores antigos, ou seja, vou ter que fazer uma mudança.

Comment: Parece que era o `this` mesmo o problema. Mudei para `xhr` pela segunda vez, e funcionou, mas da primeira não funcionou. Obrigado pelas dicas

Answer (score 0):

Observe essa linha:

```
var xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest :
```

Nota algo errado? Você esqueceu os parênteses! O correto seria isso:

```
var xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() :
```

Comment: Os parênteses são opcionais com o `new`. Se você executar `new XMLHttpRequest` no console vai ver uma nova instância. De qualquer forma, obrigado pela ajuda! O erro também não pode acontecer por isso, o código executa corretamente no IE6, tanto que ele faz até alertas no evento `onreadystatechange`.